# How to semantic-release a patch to a version that is on QA while Dev has a new minor that should not be deployed to prod?

Tags: release, patch

Our build/release process works as follows:

1. AWS CodePipeline triggers AWS CodeBuild when a PR is merged
2. CodeBuild jobs run tests and build the node package, uses semantic-release to determine the version number with `eslint` commit format, and build the docker container
3. AWS CodeDeploy deploys this container/service to the `dev` environment
4. A Manual Gate sits after, which when opened deploys the container/service to the `QA` environment
5. A similar Gate sits before `prod`

Now imagine that version `v1.5.2` was deployed to `Dev` and then deployed to `QA` via the manual gate.

Then a different PR for a different feature was created and a `v1.6.0` was release and pushed to `dev`.

But QA found that `v1.5.2` had some bug that was not discovered in unit tests or while testing on `dev`.

So now we need to release `v1.5.3` to `dev`, but will not be able to, since `v.1.6.0` has already been released.

Arguably `v.1.6.0` already contains all of `v1.5.2`, however the patch should be applied to `v1.5.2` since we may not want to rollout `v1.6.0` to `prod` for example, but we do want to get `v1.5.2` out to prod after fixing whatever bug was found on QA.

I have scoured the "semantic-release" docs and issues, but only found what says we cannot do it:

> Finally semantic-release makes releases for every new commits on
>   master in the order they get pushed. If you merge commit A to master,
>   semantic-release run and publish a release, then when you merge commit
>   B, same thing. The second release will have a higher version number
>   than the first one. If for some reasons you want commit B to be
>   released first then it has to be merged first. This behavior is
>   extremely important, because it guarantees that your git history match
>   your release history. You don't have to have a change present in 1.1.0
>   but not in 1.2.0.

Taken from reply to [issue 1213](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/1213)

Short of modifying the commit analyzer, is there any way to achieve what we've described above?

Comment: What is the "commit analyzer" you reference at the tail end of your question? Is that shorthand for describing "run tests and build the node package, semantic-release to determine the version number with eslint commit format, and build the docker container"?

Answer (score 0):

### Options

1. Add feature to your deployment pipeline to route fixes into any of your environments.
2. Remove the tight coupling between your CodeBuild gate into dev and your versioning.

### Option 1: Hot Fixes

Supporting hotfixes is allowed in semantic versioning and should resolve your problem. There are a few ways you could go about implementing this. One would be to add another manual gate that takes v1.5.3 and deploys it directly into QA, bypassing the dev environment. Depending on who is validating in QA (internal QA team vs. external user groups) this may or may not create an acceptable level of risk you're willing to take on.

If that's too risky another way to manage hotfixes is to implement a full fledge GitFlow CI process as showcased in [AWS's DevOps Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/implementing-gitflow-using-aws-codepipeline-aws-codecommit-aws-codebuild-and-aws-codedeploy/). The tutorial doesn't replicate your environment exactly, but show's how to overcome the issue you're trying to solve without compromising your versioning.

### Option 2: Environment-Versioning Decoupling

A second option is to decouple your versions from your CodeBuild gate into dev. If you're not doing so already, you can use [git tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) to track your versions (should be able to use the same semantic-release package you're currently using). Then when you need to deploy 1.5.3 into the dev environment, you roll it out like normal, removing 1.6.0 from the environment for the time being. Once you've vetted 1.5.3 in dev and can move it into QA, you can then checkout your 1.6.0 release and push it back into the dev environment.

This approach has multiple pitfalls that are more likely to happen during a major change like 2.0.0 rather than a minor one but theoretically could affect both; like what to do if 1.6.0 has database migrations? It's possible to wipe the database, take information from QA and bring it over to dev (which might be necessary to replicate the error), or restore to a previous backup. Unfortunately, all of this might need to happen outside of your automated CI environment. Similarly, if you have dependencies that rely on your dev env being at 1.6.0, you might end up breaking those in the process as well. The same types of issues can come with environment variable changes.

### Summary

I'd recommend using one of the hotfix approaches if possible but based on your existing setup, GitFlow might be overkill.